# How to prevent an image's margin from being clickable?

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the image's margin from the clickable region, without interfering in the layout of the page?

```css
#logo{
width: auto;
min-height: 80px;
margin: 30px;
height: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-aligh:center;
}
.img1 {
width: 200px;
height: 105px;
}
.img2 {
width: 200px;
height: 105px;
margin-left: 15px;
}
.img3 {
width: 200px;
height: 105px;
margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"><a href="M"><img class="img1" src="Photos/m.png"/></a>
<a href="U"><img class="img2"src="Photos/u.png" alt="U"/></a>
<a href="/#"><img class="img3" src="Photos/p.png" alt="P"/></a>
</div>
```

15px on the lower left site img2 and img3 can be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplifies your CSS declarations a bit too. In lieu of setting the margin as you had it, this sets it on `<a>` elements.

```css
#logo{
width: auto;
min-height: 80px;
margin: 30px;
height: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-aligh:center;
}


.img {
width: 200px;
height: 105px;
}

a:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <a href="M"><img class="img" src="Photos/m.png"/></a>
    <a href="U"><img class="img"src="Photos/u.png" alt="U"/></a>  
    <a href="/#"><img class="img" src="Photos/p.png" alt="P"/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the margin to the A tag instead of IMG:

```css
#logo{
  width: auto;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 30px;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.img1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 105px;
}

.img2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 105px;
}

.a2, .a3 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.img3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"><a href="M"><img class="img1" src="Photos/m.png"/></a>
<a class="a2" href="U"><img class="img2"src="Photos/u.png" alt="U"/></a>
<a class="a3" href="/#"><img class="img3" src="Photos/p.png" alt="P"/></a>
</div>
```